# How to apply erosion for only thick lines in images

Tags: python-imaging-library

Need to apply erosion only to the lines in my image which are more thicker using python

[Here is my input image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P8N1E.jpg)
I'm having a image which contains white lines with both thick and thin lines,my goal is to erode only the lines which are more thicker using python.i used normal erosion using opencv when applying this method thin lines are removing from the image.Erosion has to apply only on thick lines

```
    import cv2
    import numpy as np
    img = cv2.imread('123.png',0)
    kernel = np.ones((6,6),np.uint8)
    erosion = cv2.erode(img,kernel,iterations = 1)
    cv2.imshow("Result", erosion)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

How can i achieve this any answers will be highly useful for me.Thanks in advance

Comment: Erode your thin lines completely. Use the result as a mask. Then erode the image as desired for the thick lines. Then combine the original and the eroded image using the mask to select which parts to show from which image. See `np.where(mask=mask, eroded, original)`

Comment: Since your lines are black, change erode to dilate (or invert your image so that the lines are white). But probably better to use a close than a dilate with black lines to get the mask.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to do that in Python/OpenCV.

- Read the input as grayscale
- Threshold it
- Apply morphology close to remove the thin lines and save as a mask image
- Apply morphology dilate to the threshold image again to thin the lines
- Use np.where() to combine the threshold and dilated images using the mask
- Save the results

Input:

[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# read the input as grayscale
img = cv2.imread('black_lines.jpg', cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)

# threshold
thresh = cv2.threshold(img, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY+cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]

# apply morphology close to remove the thin lines and save as mask
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (5,5))
mask = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel)

# apply morphology dilate to thin image as desired
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (5,5))
dilate = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_DILATE, kernel)

# combine the thresh and dilate using mask
result = np.where(mask==0, dilate, thresh)

# save results
cv2.imwrite('black_lines_mask.jpg', mask)
cv2.imwrite('black_lines_dilate.jpg', dilate)
cv2.imwrite('black_lines_thinned.jpg', result)

# show results 
cv2.imshow('mask', mask)
cv2.imshow('dilate', dilate)
cv2.imshow('thinned', result)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Mask Image:

[image]

Dilate Image:

[image]

Combined Image with thin lines:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer,but unfortunately it's not working for my images.

Comment: Post another image that does not work. What have you tried to adjust?  Are the images similar?  You will need to adjust the size of the morphology kernel for each image if the lines are not the same thickness.

Comment: is there any possibility to set  constant parameter value  which work for all images?

Comment: This is my other image https://i.stack.imgur.com/1MR4R.png

Comment: No, I know of no easy way to determine that automatically. You have to adjust the threshold. Perhaps some one else might have a suggestion